# Vertex Factory in Quickgraph GraphML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, graphml, quickgraph

I've been looking for this one in a while but coudn't find anything.

I am trying to deserialize graph from GraphML using Quickgraph in C#. Here's the class I use to represent Vertex and Edge

```
[Serializable]
public class Room
{
    public Room(int id, double x, double y)
    {
        this.Ids = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Ids { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double x { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double y { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class HouseEdge<TVertex> : Edge<TVertex>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HouseEdge(TVertex source, TVertex target)
        : base(source, target)
    {
    }
}
```

And I am trying to deserialize the code using method DeserializeFromGraphML:

```
XmlReader xreader = getXMLReader("//house.xml");
IdentifiableVertexFactory<Room> ivf = new IdentifiableVertexFactory<Room>(makeTest);
IdentifiableEdgeFactory<Room, HouseEdge<Room>> ief = new IdentifiableEdgeFactory<Room, HouseEdge<Room>>(makeTest2);
graph.DeserializeFromGraphML<Room, HouseEdge<Room>, AdjacencyGraph<Room, HouseEdge<Room>>>(xreader, ivf, ief);
xreader.Close();
```

And here's the code for makeTest and makeTest2:

```
private Room makeTest(string cos)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cos);
    return new Room(11, 12.0, 13.0);
}

private HouseEdge<Room> makeTest2(Room one, Room two, string cos)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cos);
    return new HouseEdge<Room>(one, two);
}
```

So - in my XML file I got 2 vertices - (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) and edge between them. When I deserialize them edge is just fine but vertices goes (0,12,0) and (1,12,1). There has to be something that I'm missing (twelve comes from makeTest method) but `cos` variable only has number zero and one just as position of vertex in the "Vertices" of graph (that's what I'm showing in MessageBox)

I know it can be complex at first glance but maybe it's really simple? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, this is a bug in library (or there are more people that can't use this library properly).
[Here](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/discussions/243269) is one of the discussions at library forums where other pewople experience the same issues as me.

Because of this I created a code in LINQ to XML and did it manually - it work's just like navigating through normal XML. One thing to remember is to use proper XNames, because using a string as element name simply doesn't work. For example:

```
XName XNgraph = XName.Get("graph", "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns");
var edges = xelement.Elements(XNgraph)
```

Good luck if you've got this same problem as me - hope I did help you a little :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this same issue today, and found a different workaround before finding this post, in case it is useful to anyone.

I noticed as I was examining the XML output by the GraphMLSerializer, that it was deserializing properly after I would pretty-print the xml (I was using a Notepad++ plugin to make the XML easier to read). So I actually worked around it by making a slight change to my serializing code, adding a few settings to my XmlWriter so that it would pretty-print the XML it emits:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename, new XmlWriterSettings { 
        Indent = true,
        WriteEndDocumentOnClose = false
    })) {

    this.SerializeToGraphML<StoryNode, Choice, StoryArcGraph>(writer, 
        v => v.Id,
        e => e.Id
        );
}
```

My project is only ever loading XML emitted by itself, and the extra formatting characters are not an overwhelming amount of overhead, so I found this to be an acceptable workaround.